# How to send request using ESQL to a REST Request Node in ACE flow

Tags: rest, websphere, ibm-integration-bus

I have to call a REST API in my flow, that uses SSL authentication. I used a Compute Node to generate the input message and set the required header parameters in HTTPRequestHeaders. I set my Keydb file for the Integration Server that has the cert and key files.

```
SET OutputRoot.HTTPRequestHeader."Authorization" = InputRoot.HTTPRequestHeader.Authorization;
     SET OutputRoot.HTTPRequestHeader."X-WCM-TENANT-ID" = '8223028';
     SET OutputRoot.HTTPRequestHeader."X-WCM-TENANT-INSTANCE"='02';
     SET OutputRoot.HTTPRequestHeader."accept"='application/json';
     SET OutputRoot.HTTPRequestHeader."Referer" = 'curam://foundational.app';
     SET OutputRoot.HTTPRequestHeader."Content-Type"='application/json';
     
     SET OutputRoot.HTTPRequestHeader."X-GRANT-TYPE"='client_credentials';
```

```
    SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.messageID = '123';
        SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.id = 'extProviderESR5';
        SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.name = 'ext provder1 name';
        SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.description = 'ext provder1 desc';
        SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.email = 'extprovider1@example.com';
        SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.url = 'http://www.extprovider1.com';
```

```
I get 400 Bad request error. The same headers and data, if used in Postman, it creates the object. 

Can some one help me to identify , what am I missing..
```

I should be create the object using the API call

```
type here
```

Comment: Please quote the error. Without that, it's very difficult to provide any help.